# Why build a Windows Service application?

Tags: design-patterns, service, comparison

I've seen a lot of tutorials on how to create a Windows service, but.. why would one choose to create a Windows Service, when one could possibly let the application start and run as small icon in the taskbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A service allows the program to run even when there's no user logged in to the machine.

Comment: That's one thing I've found. Is that really all there is to it? Even though this is quite usefull...

Comment: Yes, the service runs independently of any logged in user.  Which can be very useful indeed.  Consider a web server for example.  You wouldn't want that to stop if you logged off of the server.  Also, you can configure the login credentials for the service so that they always stay the same regardless of which user is logged in.

Comment: That sounds fair enough, I'll accept the answer when the site will let me. Thank you. :)